# Find out who deployed database in SSAS?

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular

I have this SSAS running:
[image]

I see a database deployed and I am trying to check who deployed it, is there a DMV that I can execute somewhere that can retrieve that information?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe so, but here's a way you can guess at it!

If you look at the Properties of the server from SSMS, on the **General** page you can get the **DataDir**:

[image: Analysis Server Properties]

Go to this directory on the server. If the user is using the server as their workspace, there will be a folder for their workspace with their lan id:

[image: DataDir with userids]

The Date Modified timestamp on the folder should give you an idea who touched it last.